# Inkscape Showing Broken Arabic Letters

Tags: inkscape, fonts, pdf

After Inkscape import PDF , which have Arabic Words, Arabic Words Split into Separated Words. As a user, very new and basic with Inkscape.

Attached Arabic Names PDF and ScreenShot of Arabic Words Splitted in Inkscape.

Inkscape Version is 1.1. Using Windows 10

Appreciate your help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bugs with Inkscape need to be reported at https://inkscape.org/report . Stackexchange is not where this can be fixed.

Comment: Did Report
https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/5559
Thank You for pointing in Right Direction.